# How to sort NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

i am using `NSMutableDictionary` tho hold data and load it to a `UITableview`,
this is how the dictionary looks like :

```
    041517ba8e0542b14e96469d87bba694b42db15a =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    041517ba8e0542b14e96469d87bba694b42db15a,
    "2012-10-10 10:17:13 +0000"
);
3582a7ee9ce2e232704c3e51f27bdc9274e965c6 =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    3582a7ee9ce2e232704c3e51f27bdc9274e965c6,
    "2012-10-10 10:12:57 +0000",
    "Plastic Cup"
);
3ce8b24a9da8916f2d669f625c9eb28e77b710ec =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    3ce8b24a9da8916f2d669f625c9eb28e77b710ec,
    "2012-10-10 10:12:48 +0000",
    Headphones
);
9a2fd3bbd741e52cfc31d2a341ab79241c3048db =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    9a2fd3bbd741e52cfc31d2a341ab79241c3048db,
    "2012-10-10 10:11:58 +0000",
    "Men's Wrist Watch"
);
b7b8646cb8548e6c8cc1c83b90b9d8d3b265ed5b =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    b7b8646cb8548e6c8cc1c83b90b9d8d3b265ed5b,
    "2012-10-10 10:14:46 +0000",
    Dog
);
c30fe8901a4e14da415981ade707330bda85c2bf =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    c30fe8901a4e14da415981ade707330bda85c2bf,
    "2012-10-10 10:14:32 +0000",
    "Dog Olive"
);
d47987a197cc9b383921ef021d5469cd69e02dec =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    d47987a197cc9b383921ef021d5469cd69e02dec,
    "2012-10-10 10:12:24 +0000",
    Blurry
);
d8363eb358ce8a6266d9dae37b19628d8be8e604 =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    d8363eb358ce8a6266d9dae37b19628d8be8e604,
    "2012-10-10 10:13:08 +0000",
    "Analog Wristwatch"
);
e849e2f6d45a787fff42486cd8cb4d45499b2ef4 =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    e849e2f6d45a787fff42486cd8cb4d45499b2ef4,
    "2012-10-10 10:15:14 +0000",
    "Red Sports Car"
);
f0c5598cd2a5314d64bd25dffbef2c98be78ac0f =     (
    "{\n    size             = {360, 480}\n    CGImage.size     = {480, 360}\n    imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight\n}",
    f0c5598cd2a5314d64bd25dffbef2c98be78ac0f,
    "2012-10-10 10:12:40 +0000",
    "Laptop Computer Keyboard"
);
```

it contain a photos but not by order (added to the dictionary) what i want is to draw the `UITableView` by the order this photos are added.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary is an unsorted collection.

You should really look at putting the dictionaries or just the keys into an array.

Then you can use the array for sorting and the keys to reference the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

use `NSMutableArray` for keys and add a key to that `NSMutableArray` each time you add photo to the dictionary. The array will keep order